# Pointer allocation directly to a string? what are the drawbacks?

Tags: c, pointers, memory

so,

```
 const char *p= "hi";
```

and,

```
 char a[2]= {'h', 'i'};
 char *p= a;
```

Both of these are syntactically correct, but is there an advantage of one over the other? I used to think that you cannot do *p= "hi"; as "hi" it has not been explicitly allocated any memory like in case 2 where its defined in the array a[2].

Comment: The first example is invalid code. That's one difference.

Comment: `char *p = "hi";` is a string literal. This will most likely go in a read-only portion of your program, and any attempt to modify it is undefined behavior. `char a[2] = {'h', 'i'};` puts `a` in automatic storage, and it can be legally be modified at will. Be careful not to use `a` as a string as it has no terminating NULL byte, where as `p` does.

Comment: The first example needs` const `

Comment: You should pick one single language.

Comment: There is no such thing as "pointer allocation".

Comment: @immibis I would tend to think of `char **p = malloc(sizeof(char*))` as a "pointer allocation"...

Comment: Is this C or C++?

Comment: i thought this would scenario fits for both C and C++, I did not think this would be handled any different in either language. Also, I thought giving an example it shall be alright to skip the const and NULL terminator

Comment: @yano thank you for the answer! also is there any disadvantage in doing const char *p = "hi" over const char a[2]= {'h', 'i'}; const char *p= a; ? 

Is const char *p = "hi" doing 2 memory allocations- 1. to store "hi" and the other 2. for the pointer now pointing to "hi", which in short is same as what case 2 is?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "disadvantage". If you're going to use the string "hi" a lot of times in your program, then I would keep it as a string literal. The compiler should be smart enough to keep one copy of "hi" in memory and point any number of instances of `char *p="hi";` to that string (better yet you should just `#define` it). If you want to eventually modify "hi", then you absolutely cannot make it a string literal as that would lead to UB. In the first case, `p` is a pointer in automatic storage (most likely the stack) that points to "hi". In the second, both `a` and `p` go on

Comment: the stack (`'h'`, `'i'`, and `p` pointing to `'h'` go on the stack). You can freely modify the contents of `a` (via `a` or `p` access) as long as those variables are in scope. So it depends on your situation which one is "better". If you're asking which one is faster/more memory efficient,, technically the 2nd case is one less byte because there is no NULL terminator. I wouldn't expect one to be faster than the other. All of my comments apply to `c` only.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, `p` is read only (const), read only memory is 'faster' because the compiler can optimize it. Also p is *actually* equal to `'h', 'i', '\0'`

The second p is modifiable, you can do operations such as `p[0] = 'd'`. However you need to get that `'\0'` at the end of the string if you want to print it out anywhere.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Explain

Comment: Well, it's not the case that the literal in the first example is faster because it's read-only. The data isn't necessarily placed in read only memory (but it's UB to try to modify it). And it doesn't even compile as C++, that should be mentioned. And both examples can be optimized.

It does avoid the implied copying in the second example, but that's likely to be optimized away too.